# Simple in-process key-value store, usable in distributed proprietary programs

Tags: open-source, library, cobol, key-value-store

Currently GnuCOBOL uses Berkeley DB for `INDEXED SEQUENTIAL` file access (essentially a persistent key-value store). However, versions after 1.85 (which is buggy) have copyleft licenses that prohibit them from being used in distributed proprietary programs.

Older simple, non-relational DBMSs exist, but data size limits make them unusable. SQLite is overkill for this, being a full SQL RDBMS.

Does anyone know of a library that would meet the needs of GnuCOBOL? If not, one probably needs to be written.

Comment: "data size limits": Please be more explicit: What should be the minimum capacity of the store? (number of keys, size of values, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library to use in this case: [VB-ISAM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vbisam/). **Make sure to use a 2.x version.**

VB-ISAM is licensed under LGPL 2.1+

Build it from source and install the library, afterwards you can configure GnuCOBOL to use it by rebuilding libcob: `configure --with-vbisam` and updating the system with the new one.
There's no need to recompile any module already compiled with `cobc`.